# i18n - Should the page URIs be translated on a regional website?

Tags: internationalization, standards, translation

I'm working on a regional ecommerce website (ie. usa, uk, china) that offers a unique product line for each country. The site's URLs are currently in english only. Should these URLs be translated into the region's language? Are site URLs usually translated on regional sites?

**Example URLs:**
http://domain.com/products
http://domain.com/collection/a_product_line
http://domain.com/styles
http://domain.com/press_room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always translate URLs for regional sites. I believe there are several advantages to that:

1. More search engine friendly
2. Links are more recognizable by humans, they are easier to pronounce and to communicate to the users and among them (over the telephone, on ads and commercials, among friends, etc...)
3. The user confidence and familiarity is improved, as the user will better perceive that the site "speaks his language", and is not just a mete translation from a different language

Answer (score 1):

It's by no means necessary, but I'd call it a very user friendly practice.

Monster has solved it by translating subdomains, I like that very much:

Monster.com:
http://jobsearch.monster.com/Search.aspx?brd=1&q=java&cy=us&lid=316&re=130

Monster.es (Spain):
http://buscartrabajo.monster.es/Search.aspx?q=java&cy=es&lid=166&re=130

although it should be 
http://buscartrabajo.monster.es/Buscar.aspx?q=java&cy=es&lid=166&re=130